# Approximation using Legendre polynomials

Tags: statistics, regression, orthogonal-polynomials

my aim is to fit data points by the use of Legendre Polynomials. Has anybody experience with this task? My final aim is to do this automatically with mathematica.

Thanks,
rainer

Comment: "My final aim is to do this automatically with mathematica" - Look up `Fit[]`

Answer (score 1):

Is it enough to use to Legendre Polynomials as basis within the Fit[] Function. 
Fit[data,{LegendreP[1,x],LegendreP[2,x],LegendreP[3,x]},x]
I would be glad about an explanation how it actually works. Thx rainer

Comment: You've forgotten the constant term: `Fit[data, {1, LegendreP[1, x], LegendreP[2, x], LegendreP[3, x]}, x]`

Comment: The problem is for an arbitrary set of data points this produces exactely the same solution as: Fit[data, {1,x,x^2,x^3}, x]. So I do not understand what the special thing about Legendre Approximation is.